# Oracle Apex- Format mask in USD format

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to format mask a column into USD format.
The number would be saved in number format only, just display should be with a dollar.
The format mask i use in attributes, that come in options :for example, $5234.34 does not add the dollar sign.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: "A column". In what component ? A classic report, an interactive report or an interactive grid ? If it is an IG, is this an editable column ? You're more likely to get an answer if your question has enough information for someone with no access to your system to reproduce it.

Comment: Its a column in a form: a page item with NUMBER as datatype

Comment: that is not commonly referred to as "a column" ;) It is a "Page Item".

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me. I created a from on `EMP` and changed the format mask for salary to FML999G999G999G999G990D00 using the following steps:

1. Click on the menu next to "Format Mask" which shows the popup below:
   [image]
2. Select the first value which returns format mask FML999G999G999G999G990D00
3. Value in the form looks like this:

[image]

This format is determined by the "Application Primary Language". For me that is set to "English (United States) en-us". If I change that to another language, the $ is replaced by the currency symbol of the selected language. This is set in Shared Components > Application Definition Attributes > Globalization.

You can override this value by manually setting it in an application process (Process point "On Load: Before Header") with source:

```
execute immediate q'!alter session set nls_currency='$'!';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin:

https://github.com/grlicaa/AutoNumeric

Formats the number as the user types in the page item and sends the value in number format to the server